# how to recode the categorical variable to ordinal based on the event rate of another variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, categorical-data

I have a dataframe in python with many categorical variables and the target variable is binary. I want to convert the categorical variable to ordinal based on the rank of target variable event rate (same to mean of target variable) on each category of the variable. For example, if below is my original dataset

[image]

For each category on column1, aka, 'A' and 'B', we have:
[image]

For each categry on column2, aka, 'C','D','E','F','G', we have:

[image]

So I want to be able to create the final dataset like this:

[image]

How can i create one like that?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the `mean` for each `grouped` category value, `rank` the result and `map` to category values. Sample data for illustration:

```
import string
abc = string.ascii_uppercase
df = pd.DataFrame({'target': np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=10), 'col1': np.random.choice(list(abc[:2]), size=10), 'col2': np.random.choice(list(abc[:5]), size=10)})

  col1 col2  target
0    B    B       0
1    A    E       0
2    B    A       1
3    B    E       1
4    A    A       0
5    A    E       0
6    B    D       1
7    A    E       0
8    A    E       1
9    B    B       0
```

Code along the above lines to produce both columns:

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2']:
    df[col] = df.loc[:, col].map(df.groupby(col).target.mean().rank().astype(int))

   col1  col2  target
0     2     1       0
1     1     2       0
2     2     3       1
3     2     2       1
4     1     3       0
5     1     2       0
6     2     4       1
7     1     2       0
8     1     2       1
9     2     1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a `transform`. Lets look at the following ...

```
col1 col2  target
0    A    D       1
1    A    A       0
2    A    E       0
3    B    A       0
4    A    C       0
5    A    D       1
6    B    E       0
7    A    C       0
8    B    C       0
9    B    B       0
```

You can get a transformation using `groupby` as:

```
df.groupby('col1').transform(np.mean)

     target
0  0.333333
1  0.333333
2  0.333333
3  0.000000
4  0.333333
5  0.333333
6  0.000000
7  0.333333
8  0.000000
9  0.000000
```

Now, you only need the series information of transform ...

```
df.groupby('col1').transform(np.mean)['target']
0    0.333333
1    0.333333
2    0.333333
3    0.000000
4    0.333333
5    0.333333
6    0.000000
7    0.333333
8    0.000000
9    0.000000
```

A `pd.Series` can be converted into a factor in several different ways. One way is to use `pd.factorize()`.

```
pd.factorize(df.groupby('col1').transform(np.mean)['target'])
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]),
 Float64Index([0.333333333333, 0.0], dtype='float64'))
```

Of which you are only looking for the factored values:

```
pd.factorize(df.groupby('col1').transform(np.mean)['target'])[0]
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

Now, just assign it the the column name of your choice :).

Hope this helps ...